# Crypt::Tea installation error: Finding Crypt::Tea on cpanmetadb failed

Tags: perl, ubuntu-16.04, cpan

I am struggling to up my system after updating the `Ubuntu` from `14.04` to `16.04`, A module `Crypt::Tea` ([not referring this one with Crypt::TEA)](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::TEA) is not getting installed. Its 32bit OS.

Command `cpanm Crypt::Tea` getting following error.

`$ sudo cpanm Crypt::Tea
! Finding Crypt::Tea on cpanmetadb failed.
! Finding Crypt::Tea () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution Crypt::Tea`

Now the perl version is `5.22.1`.

It was working with `perl 5.18` and `Ubuntu 14.04`.
Need help to resolve this to make available following routine.

`&encrypt($myjson, $myclient->{key});`

Comment: The module is called `Crypt::TEA`, not `Crypt::Tea`. Module names are **case-sensitive**.

Comment: Nonetheless, the installation for 1.25 fails for me on Perl 5.20.1. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 too, but my Perl is not the system Perl, so that doesn't matter. Looks like it stopped working with 5.18: http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Crypt-TEA+1.25

Comment: This lib hasn't changed since 2001, I'm curious, what are you using it for?

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche, yew this is very old code and its using `&encrypt($myjson, $myclient->{key})`

Comment: @simbabque, thank you very much for correcting me, I have updated my question.

Comment: @simbabque, I think Crypt::Tea is obsolete now, refer Credit section `Based on Crypt::Tea_JS (and, in Old-mode, Crypt::Tea)` of http://search.cpan.org/~pjb/Crypt-Tea_JS-2.23/bin/tea, now its became Crypt::Tea_JS.

Comment: So did you figure this out?

Comment: Now I am using Crypt::Tea_JS and its working, I have also find out the older version Crypt::Tea, its now in backpan http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/P/PJ/PJB/Crypt-Tea-2.12.tar.gz.